# Membership and Slicing behaviour of tuple abstraction

Tags: python-3.x

For operators like `+` `*` etc.., we have function behaviours like `add` `mul`. 
`tuple` abstraction provides `count()` and `index(,)` function behaviours for users. 
Do we have a functional notation in python to use below two membership behaviours `in` and `not in`?

```
>>> digits = (1, 8, 2, 8)
>>> 2 in digits
True
>>> 1828 not in digits
True
```

Do we have a functional notation in python to use below Slicing behaviour `[x:y]`?

```
>>> digits[0:2]
(1, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

For `in` you can use [`operator.contains(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.contains) and [`operator.not_(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.__not__) for `not` but for `not in` there is not an special function.but you can mix them so `not_(contains(a,b))` will be the equivalent of `not in`:

```
>>> a=(1,2,3)
>>> from operator import not_,contains
>>> contains(a,2)
True
>>> contains(a,4)
False
>>> not_(contains(a,4))
True
```